# Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\li b\tools.jar

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ant, build

When I try to run the following command I get an error:

```
$ ant -Dsdk.dir=/opt/google/appengine-java-sdk runserver -Dserver.host=192.168.1.10
```

Here is the error:

> "Unable to locate tools.jar. Expected to find it in C:\Program
>   Files\Java\jre6\li b\tools.jar".

I have given jdk path in `JAVA_HOME` variable as `C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.6.0_25` as my jdk location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_25`.

What is the issue?  Please help me.Thanks in advance.

When I have tried to run the command ant -diagnostics , I got

```
java.home : C:\Program Files\Java\jre6
```

Comment: are you aware of the space character between "li" and "b" in that path? I highly doubt that it's supposed to be there ;)

Comment: that might just be a typo

Comment: JRE does not have tools.jar. Judging from the path it seems that `ant` still loads JRE instead of JDK.

Comment: How can I make it to load JDK?

Answer (score 23):

You should try adding %JAVA_HOME%\bin at the beginning of your PATH environment variable (given syntax assumes Windows of course).
As Peter Knego commented, tools.jar exists in the JDK, not the JRE, so you must make sure the JAVA_HOME points to your JDK directory.

Comment: %JAVA_HOME%\bin present at the end of path so changed position i.e added at the beginning of your PATH environment variable. It works!! but whats difference ?

Comment: Well, when the OS tries to locate an executable, it will try all the locations listed in the PATH, in the order they are listed. So if you really want something to be found, put it at the beginning, in case an executable by the same name is also found at some other locations. That's probably what caused your problem: either another java executable can be found in one of the existing PATH locations, or somehow you jumbled the PATH syntax somewhere in the middle and the last portion of the PATH is unusable. At leat that's the most likely causes.

Comment: %JAVA_HOME%\lib at beginning of path, if you want to load tools.jar

Answer (score 2):

You are probably building some project that has the old file called `local.properties` at the project root level. There is a `sdk.dir` property there and it is pointing wrongly. Open that file with editor and correct.

Also, your command line looks questionable. There you specify the sdk location using some Unix path and from the rest of you message looks you are on Windows. Be sure that property matches your sdk location. It may not be actually required at all.

Comment: The command is to  set up the server using a standard App Engine for Java for Google Cloud Messaging and I am working in Windows.

Comment: Where are you building the project, locally or on the server?